# Convert minutes to hundredths excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to prepare an Excel formula that do the following time equation:

04:15:30 should converted as 04:25

18:30:15 should converted as 18:50

33:45:59 should converted as 33:75

30:14:14 should converted as 30:23

This formula should convert minutes to hundredths and should not do any thing with the hours such as above example.

I have searched for hours and could find the exact excel formula such this one.

```
FIRST NOTE : if you make some improve on this formula (=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1*24,"00.00"),".",":")) it could be help.

SECOND NOTE : as above formula note that it should not have any excel date conversion such as (MINUTE,HOUR,[hh]...etc)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have test it, when i add time (33:30:33) it gave me (1.:160) and the correct result should be (33:50), please help!

Comment: Good solution , but please read my question again, i have mentioned that the formula shouldn't have any date or time functions like this =(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1*24,"00.00"),".",":"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said inside my comment: Your `33:45:59` is converted date/time while you want ppl to convert it without using the buildin convert of excel.

Having your times as string as they are, this formula works perfect:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&":"&TEXT(MID(A1,4,2)/3*5,"00")
=LEFT(A1,2)&TEXT(MID(A1,4,2)/3*5,""":""00")
```

But as said: it is already converted to time/date and stored as double. So your `33:45:59` is `1.40693287037037`. (this way `=LEFT(A1,2)` is `"1."` and not `"33"`.

To change it like it is, you would need a formula like this:

```
=TRUNC(A1*24)&":"&TEXT(ROUND(MOD(A1*2400,100)-MOD(A1*1440,1)/3*5,0),"00")
```

Or if you want to round over seconds then:

```
=TRUNC(A1*24)&":"&TEXT(ROUND(MOD(A1*2400,100),"00")
```

if also `TEXT` is not alowed then you need something like this:

```
=TRUNC(A1*24)&":"&IF(ROUND(MOD(A1*2400,100)-MOD(A1*1440,1)/3*5,0)<10,0,"")&ROUND(MOD(A1*2400,100)-MOD(A1*1440,1)/3*5,0)
=TRUNC(A1*24)&":"&IF(ROUND(MOD(A1*2400,100),0,"")&ROUND(MOD(A1*2400,100)
```

As a side note: the formula  `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1*24,"00.00"),".",":")` doesn't contain any date/time functions.

**EDIT**

Using substitude it would look like this: (full value in A1)

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(ABS(TRUNC(FLOOR((A1-"220:00"-(59/86400)*((A1-"220:00")<0))*24,IF((A1-"220:00")<0,-1/60,1/60)),2)),"00.00"),".",":")&IF((A1-"220:00")<0,"-","")
```

The `-(59/86400)*((A1-"220:00")<0)` part is to ensure it works properly. Without, negative numbers with seconds will be round down by 1 minute... just math :)

Comment: Wow, you make it.
But one thing missing , sorry for forget to mention it , that if you add minus (-) to the time it will not be accepted (ex: 12:15:55- should be 12:25-) but unfortunately it is (12:25)
please help this is the last thing.
i would appreciate if you modify this on (=TEXT(A1,"[hh]") & ":" & FLOOR(MINUTE(A1)*100/60,1))

Comment: Yes sir, my leader did not accept any form of date like ([hh]) or MINUTES , but i would appreciate if you provide me with formula that accept minus (-) plz.

Comment: Then tell your leader that I need to know what really is in the cell for `33:33:33` and `33:33:33-` (as it looks right now the first will be something like `1.4....` but for negative I'm sure it is not `-1.4....`

Comment: You are right, the issue had some misunderstanding, but he needs it to provide total employee attendance plus or minus hours per month (ex :  employee X works 220:12:55 hour in last month but expected hours should be 220:00:00 ) so the employee X works for 00:12:55 plus hours and other one works 01:22:13- (minus) hours last month.
Thats the issue i'm looking a solution for it.

Comment: Excel tells me that ( the formula you typed contained an error ) it seems like missing something maybe parentheses.
Danke schon

Comment: I need to check that... (till now all done by phone without excel)... I'll give some feedback as soon as possible :)

Comment: Ja ich verstehe das , Danke Herr

Comment: Unfortunately Dear, it not work never, your formula up side downs the result (11:30 became 208:50-) hehehe i don't know why, sorry to take a lot of your time, i appreciate for more help.

Comment: @mustafamohammed as said: "use it with the full time" ***ex : employee X works 220:12:55 hour in last month...*** use it with the *220:12:55* not with the *00:12:55*... I still do not know how the real cell value looks like for positive and negative values :(

Comment: Dear Dirk, simple the positive or negative values maybe any time you imagine like (12:12:20 OR 222:22:13 OR 01:05:20-) in addition the last function you add above does not work (i try to add 220:12:55 it converted to 00:20) pleasssse help , i'm in trouple.

Answer (score 1):

Its rather simple: format a cell as number with two decimals, make the formula `=A1*24`.

The time format is internally stored as days with fractions of a day.

To cut if seconds, you should instead use `=HOUR(A1) &MINUTE(A1)/60`

Comment: Sorry, but not the answer i looking for.

Comment: Oh man, please read my question again, i have mentioned that the formula shouldn't have any date or time functions like this =(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1*24,"00.00"),".",":"))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might work for you:

```
=MAX((24*INT(A1))+((A1-INT(A1))*24),(-1*((24*INT(A1))+((A1-INT(A1))*24))))
```

Comment: Thanks i will check that

Comment: Sir i tried it but Excel does not accept it, Excel says that the Formula has something wrong, would you please check it for me again.

Comment: No errors when I tried it again.   Sounds like you might have just left off a parenthesis...or put the formula in cell "A1".   This formula only works for one cell, but you can always drag it down.